# Python random.sample not working properly?

Tags: python, random

I'm a complete nab with python.
But now I need a simple storage containing MyObject-objects for some project.
Each object contains a few StringProperties nothing fancy.

Now I want to get from my list of MyObjects, 10 random objects and store them in some other array.

So I went searching and found random.sample and started implemending it.

```
def get10RandomMyObjects():
    # waarders maken
    dict = {}
    myObjectsList = []

    # Lijst vullen
    myObjects = MyObject.all()

    randomMyObjects = random.sample(myObjects, 10)

    for o in randomMyObjects:
        dict_myObject = { }
        #some random property setting
        myObjectsList.append(dict_myObject)

    dict['myObjects'] = myObjectsList
    return dict
```

This is the error I get back:

```
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/random.py", line 314, in sample
    n = len(population)
TypeError: object of type 'Query' has no len()
```

So obviously something is wrong with the random.sample but my noobness can't decypher what it is.
Anyone care to explain me why I can't obtain those 10 random MyObjects I so desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.sample()` works on lists. Obviously, `MyObject.all()` does not return a list but a `Query` object. If `Query` is at least iterable then you can write:

```
myObjects = list(MyObject.all())
```

Otherwise, you have to create a list from `MyObject.all()` manually.

Comment: It was that damned Query object indeed. Thanks for making me understand it a little better.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Query object is a generator.    `random.sample` likes to know how many items there are in order to create the sample.    So the simplest thing to do is put the items to be  sampled in a list:

```
randomMyObjects = random.sample(list(myObjects), 10)
```

Comment: The list comprehension is more idiomatically written `list(myObjects)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `random.sample()`. What is happening is that `myObjects` is not a collection.

Most likely, `myObjects` is an iterator. You'll have to turn it into a list before using it in `random.sample()`:

```
randomMyObjects = random.sample(list(myObjects),10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use:

```
randomMyObjects = MyObject.all().order_by('?')[:10]
```

Which is faster because it will let the database do the random ordering and only load the 10 first objects into memory.